# Count instances of number in Row

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-query-language

I have a sheet formated somewhat like this

```
 Thing         5  6  7  Person 1  Person 2   Person 3 

 Thing 1          1  2      7         7          6

 Thing 2          5                   5 

 Thing 3          7         6         6

 Thing 4          6         6         5
```

I am trying to find a query formula that I can place in the columns labeled 5,6,7 that will count the number of people who have that amount of Thing 1. For example, I filled out the Thing 1 row, showing that 1 person has 6 of Thing 1 and 2 people have 7 of Thing 1.

Comment: Provide screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function: "COUNTIF".
The formula to write in the cells will look like this:

```
=COUNTIF(E2:G2;"=5")
```

For more information regarding this function, check the documentation: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en